# Release Management Tokenization - how to access Build number as a Token within Component

Tags: release-management, ms-release-management

The footer of my application currently contains Release information that is set in the web config.  Right now, after every release, I manually update this config value to `REL 2.0.1` or `2.0.3`, etc.  The build that we use in our RM path is always named in this fashion.

I'm seeking automation of this process via tokenization - I'd like to have a `__ReleaseNumber__` token in my config, and then set it from within RM by parsing the REL number from the name of the build.  Is there any way to achieve this, or is manual my only option?

Answer (score 2):

This should not be a Release responsibility. RM tokens are used for things that change values between stages, which is not the case for your scenario - at least not for the version number.

The version number in your config file should be set at build time. There is many existing custom activities to achieve this ([here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/archive/2009/11/18/how-to-create-a-custom-workflow-activity-for-tfs-build-2010.aspx) is an example for TFS 2010, something else [here](http://blog.thavo.com/2013/07/tfs-build-number-used-as.html)).

If you want a combination of some text (like Dev 2.0.1, then Rel 2.0.1 in another stage) and the version number, then you can add tokens to set that part.

Comment: Really, this shouldn't even be a build responsibility. If the version number is being set for the assemblies in `AssemblyInfo.cs`, it's easy enough to pull the version number out at runtime.